# how to create extra post thumbnail with merge of an icon image?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am searching a way to merge image of play button icon to featured image of the post.
Bay be possible between add_image_size process.

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
    add_image_size( 'post-play-icon', 90, 62, true ); //(cropped)
}
```

Comment: WP doesn't really include much in terms of image manipulation (outside of crop/resize). If you are not sure how to implement overlay in generic PHP that should probably be first and separate question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't take this route. Instead I would apply a PNG client-side, using CSS. This has the advantage of allowing you to swap out your play icon as you see fit.

Comment: thanks for your advice! I already use that css but it was my pending thought now a little free time so I try to bring a solution of this without css. maybe use direct php and gd lib

Comment: CSS will be much better solution in this case. You can add hover effects on this play button then. If you merge it into original thumbnail, it won't be possible.

Comment: Yes my dear friend you are right I am agreed with you. but I just complete this thing too for increasing positive energy. almost I am finish but I preferred css. thanks again for your advice.